# Is there a general criteria to determine where a strongly correlated system is gapped or gapless

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

First, in a number conserving system, does "gapped" mean 
$$E^{(1)}_N-E^{(0)}_N=finite$$
where $E^{(l)}_N$ is the $l$-th excited state energy with particle number $N$? Then how to determine whether a system is gapped or not by glancing its Hamiltonian?

For example, is the original (rather than the mean-field one) BCS Hamiltonian 
$$
H=\sum\limits_{\bf{k}\sigma}\xi_{\bf{k}}c^\dagger_{\bf{k}\sigma}c_{\bf{k}\sigma}+\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{\bf{kk'}}V_{\bf{kk'}}c^\dagger_{\bf{k\uparrow}}c^\dagger_{-\bf{k}\downarrow}c_{-\bf{k}'\downarrow}c_{\bf{k}'\uparrow}$$
gapped or gapless? How to prove? (It would be OK if you use mean-field theory provided you prove that this approximation doesn't change the gappedness.)

And is the Hubbard model (for fermions) gapped?

Also, is the following Hamiltonian with "spinless fermions" gapped?
$$
H=-\sum_{l}[(c^\dagger_lc_{l+1}+H.c.)+\mu c^\dagger_lc_l-U\hat{n}_l\hat{n}_{l+1}]
$$

References of any level is appreciated.

Comment: A general comment: being gapped or gapless is generally thought of as a property of a *ground state*, not a *Hamiltonian*. So the Hubbard model at half filling can, depending on the ratio of tunnelling to interaction energy, has a gapless ground state (the metallic state) or a gapped ground state (the Mott insulating state).

Comment: @Rococo Really? I always had the impression that this is thought of a property in the Hamiltonian.  Of course, it shows up in the scaling correlations of the ground state, so it is not so different (though only the implication gapped => exponential decay is rigorous).  Nevertheless, when e.g. thinking of stability of phases, the Hamiltonian seems to be the relevant object!

Comment: @Lagrenge Your question is hard to answer as it is posed now:  On the one hand, you ask a very general question ("Is there a criterion"), and then you simply list a number of examples (well, classes of examples), without saying why you care about those.  The answer to the question in the title is "No", and for each case it will heavily depend on the parameters.  I think as it is posed now it is too broad.  Do you mind narrowing it down to clarify what you really want to know?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04135

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I guess that, within the grand canonical ensemble, as long as you give the actual ratios of all the energy scales ($\mu$, $U$, and $t$ for the Hubbard model),  this uniquely determines the state as far as I know. But certainly if you just write down a form like the Hubbard Hamiltonian without specifying the relations between these parameters, one cannot say whether the ground state is a gapped phase (such as Mott or band insulator), or gapless phase (such as metallic).

Comment: @Rococo My problem is more fundamental: I don't see why "gapped" should be a property of the the ground state!  Gapped-ness is a spectral property of a (family of) Hamiltonians.  You can easily write down different properties of Hamiltonians with very different spectral properties, yet they have the same ground state!  (In particular, one is stable against perturbations and another one isn't, which is IMO the whole point why people care about gaps!)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Okay, maybe I am causing some confusion by being needlessly imprecise. When I say "ground state property" I really mean "ground state and low-lying excitations." I agree with the OP's general definition of gapped. My point is nonetheless that the OP's question as stated doesn't make sense because the Hubbard model, and a class of Hamiltonians generally, have phases which are gapped and others which are gapless (in the sense of the OP), so one has to do something like make a phase diagram and label which regimes are which.

Comment: If this doesn't line up with how you think about gaps, then maybe we are talking about subtly different things.

Comment: @Rococo Ok, that sounds better. "Ground state and low-lying excitations" is quite different from "ground state".  Clearly, for Hamiltonian families as asked by the OP, there is a different answer for every Hamiltonian (i.e. every setting of parameters).  That's why I think this question is too broad -- the OP is asking both about a general definition AND lots of cases.  ---  On a different note, I do NOT fully agree with the definition: the particle number does not make much sense here, it should be a density or sth. similar.